# SpookyJS example/hello.js fails with "throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event"

Tags: node.js, spookyjs

When I run the hello example from [SpookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS), it fails with the following error:

```
$ node examples/hello.js
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
  at errnoException (child_process.js:998:11)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:34)
```

In fact, all examples that I tried result in this error. I'm stuck, as I cannot interpret the error message even when looking into the source code. Do you have any ideas?

(I'm using Ubuntu with phantomjs 1.9.7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: `npm install -g casperjs`

I assumed that it is enough to call `npm install` locally, but `casperjs` must be in the path. After I installed `casperjs` globally, the example worked fine.